# Problems encoding video with Android NDK camera API

Tags: android, encoding, camera, android-ndk, video-recording

I'm traying to write an App with NDK camera API but I'm facing issues with encoding, this is my code (sorry for code identation).

```
static void image_reader_on_image_available(void *context,
                                        AImageReader *reader){
media_status_t media_status;
AImage *image = NULL;

media_status = AImageReader_acquireLatestImage(reader, &image);
if (media_status != AMEDIA_OK) {
    LOGI("No image available.");
    return;
}

size_t bufferSize = 0;
int inputBufferIdx = AMediaCodec_dequeueInputBuffer(mediaCodec, -1);
uint8_t *inputBuffer = AMediaCodec_getInputBuffer(mediaCodec, inputBufferIdx, &bufferSize);

if (inputBufferIdx >= 0) {
   LOGI("dequeue input buffer (size: %u)", bufferSize);
   int dataSize = 0;
   AImage_getPlaneData(image, 0, &inputBuffer, &dataSize);
   LOGI("copying image buffer (size: %d)", dataSize);

   int64_t timestamp = 0;
   AImage_getTimestamp(image, &timestamp);

   AMediaCodec_queueInputBuffer(mediaCodec, inputBufferIdx, 0, bufferSize, timestamp, 0);
}

AMediaCodecBufferInfo bufferInfo;
int idx = AMediaCodec_dequeueOutputBuffer(mediaCodec, &bufferInfo, -1);

LOGI("dequeue output buffer idx: %d", idx);

if (idx == AMEDIACODEC_INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
   AMediaFormat *format = AMediaCodec_getOutputFormat(mediaCodec);

   tidx = AMediaMuxer_addTrack(mediaMuxer, format);
   LOGI("added track tidx: %d (format: %s)", tidx, AMediaFormat_toString(format));

   AMediaMuxer_start(mediaMuxer);
   AMediaFormat_delete(format);

} else if (idx >= 0) {

 uint8_t *outputBuffer = AMediaCodec_getOutputBuffer(mediaCodec, idx, &bufferSize);

 if (tidx >= 0 && bufferInfo.size > 0) {
   pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

   LOGI("sending buffer to tidx: %d ptr: %p (info->offset: %d, info->size: %d)", tidx, outputBuffer, bufferInfo.offset, bufferInfo.size);
   AMediaMuxer_writeSampleData(mediaMuxer, tidx, outputBuffer, &bufferInfo);

      pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }

    AMediaCodec_releaseOutputBuffer(mediaCodec, idx, false);
  }

  AImage_delete(image);
}
```

Start recording

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_freedesktop_nativecamera2_NativeCamera2_startRecording(JNIEnv *env,
                                                                                   jclass clazz,
                                                                                   int fd,
                                                                                   jobject surface) {
int32_t width, height;
media_status_t media_status;

pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);

theNativeWindow = ANativeWindow_fromSurface(env, surface);
mediaMuxer = AMediaMuxer_new(fd, AMEDIAMUXER_OUTPUT_FORMAT_MPEG_4);

width = 640; //ANativeWindow_getWidth(theNativeWindow);
height = 480; //ANativeWindow_getHeight(theNativeWindow);

LOGI("Setting ImageReader (w: %d, h: %d)\n", width, height);

AImageReader_new(width, height,
                 AIMAGE_FORMAT_YUV_420_888,
                 5, /* maxImages */
                 &imageReader);

media_status = AImageReader_getWindow(imageReader, &imageReaderWindow);
if (media_status != AMEDIA_OK) {
   LOGE("Failed to get a native window from image reader.");
   return;
}

imageReaderListener.onImageAvailable = image_reader_on_image_available;
AImageReader_setImageListener(imageReader, &imageReaderListener);

mediaCodec = AMediaCodec_createEncoderByType("video/avc");

AMediaFormat *mediaFormat = AMediaFormat_new();

/** These are mandatory to configure mediacodec. */
AMediaFormat_setString(mediaFormat, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_MIME, "video/avc");
//AMediaFormat_setInt32(mediaFormat, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_BIT_RATE, 125000);
AMediaFormat_setFloat(mediaFormat, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_FRAME_RATE, 15.0);
AMediaFormat_setInt32(mediaFormat, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);
AMediaFormat_setInt32(mediaFormat, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_WIDTH, width);
AMediaFormat_setInt32(mediaFormat, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_HEIGHT, height);
AMediaFormat_setInt32(mediaFormat, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, 0x7f420888 /*COLOR_FormatYUV420Flexible*/);

media_status = AMediaCodec_configure(mediaCodec, mediaFormat, NULL, NULL, AMEDIACODEC_CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE); 
if (media_status != AMEDIA_OK) {
    LOGE("Failed to configure media codec(return code: %x)", media_status);
}


AMediaFormat_delete(mediaFormat);

openCamera(TEMPLATE_RECORD);

ACameraOutputTarget_create(theNativeWindow, &cameraOutputTarget);
ACaptureRequest_addTarget(captureRequest, cameraOutputTarget);

ACameraOutputTarget_create(imageReaderWindow, &imageReaderOutputTarget);
ACaptureRequest_addTarget(captureRequest, imageReaderOutputTarget);

ACaptureSessionOutput_create(theNativeWindow, &sessionOutput);
ACaptureSessionOutputContainer_add(captureSessionOutputContainer, sessionOutput);

ACaptureSessionOutput_create(imageReaderWindow, &imageReaderSessionOutput);
ACaptureSessionOutputContainer_add(captureSessionOutputContainer, imageReaderSessionOutput);

ACameraDevice_createCaptureSession(cameraDevice, captureSessionOutputContainer,
                                   &captureSessionStateCallbacks, &captureSession);

ACameraCaptureSession_setRepeatingRequest(captureSession, NULL, 1, &captureRequest, NULL);

AMediaCodec_start(mediaCodec);
}
```

after runing,video recording is stored in green color. I only see green color when I playing it.

I tried different media format but I do not kown if I'm missing somenthing

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, have you been able to solve this?